# Access denied on Certutil -backupKey

Tags: windows, certificate, pki

I got access denied when trying to do a certutil -backupKey. I already have Domain Admin and access to the CA cert (Read, Issue/Manage Certificates, Manage CA, Request Certificates). What Am I missing? I need to export the backup with the private key.

```
> Certutil: -backupKey command FAILED: 0x8007005 <WIN32:5> Certutil:
> Access is denied
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use an account with Enterprise admin. Domain admin is not enough (as I just spent 3 hours figuring out...)